# How to configure the content of slurm notification emails?

Tags: slurm

Slurm can notify the user by email when certain types of events occur using options such as   `--mail-type` and `--mail-user`.

The emails I receive this way contain a void body and a title that looks like :

> SLURM Job_id=9228 Name=toto Ended, Run time 07:32:31, COMPLETED, ExitCode 0

I'd like to configure slurm so that the title or even better the body of the email contains other informations in a similar way of what the slurm command `squeue --format` returns.

(actually I'd like the email to contain the comment I set up using `sbatch --comment`)

Answer (score 3):

To customise the email sent by Slurm, you typically write a script and set the value of `MailProg` to the path to that script in your `slurm.conf`.

From the doc, `MailProg` is:

> Fully qualified pathname to the program used to send email per user
>   request. The default value is "/bin/mail" (or "/usr/bin/mail" if
>   "/bin/mail" does not exist but "/usr/bin/mail" does exist).

The `contrib` directory of the Slurm source contains a script written in Perl that you can use and customise: https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/tree/master/contribs/seff

Comment: I am not an administrator. How do I display the contents of the `slurm.conf` file?

Comment: in your answer, you say `you typically write a script`. What is the purpose of that script? Do you mind providing a small example of such a script that modifies the body of the e-mail to be sent? If you have one in Python that'd be ideal! :-)

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/mail` a directory or a file? What is that suppose to be?

Comment: If you are not the administrator, you will not be able to modify the Slurm configuration. The script I am talking about can be the `smail` script in the referred-to GitHub repository. `/usr/bin/mail` is a program used to send emails on the Linux command line

Comment: so I cannot as a user choose the body of the e-mail sent to me?

Comment: Not the one sent automatically.  But you still add a command in your submission script to send an email.

Answer (score 2):

See my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73293511/10597279)

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J MyModel
#SBATCH -n 1 # Number of cores
#SBATCH -t 1-00:00 # Runtime in D-HH:MM
#SBATCH -o JOB%j.out # File to which STDOUT will be written
#SBATCH -e JOB%j.out # File to which STDERR will be written
#SBATCH --mail-type=BEGIN
#SBATCH --mail-user=my@email.com

secs_to_human(){
    echo "$(( ${1} / 3600 )):$(( (${1} / 60) % 60 )):$(( ${1} % 60 ))"
}
start=$(date +%s)
echo "$(date -d @${start} "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"): ${SLURM_JOB_NAME} start id=${SLURM_JOB_ID}\n"

### exec task here
( << replace with your task here >> ) \
&& (cat JOB$SLURM_JOB_ID.out |mail -s "$SLURM_JOB_NAME Ended after $(secs_to_human $(($(date +%s) - ${start}))) id=$SLURM_JOB_ID" my@email.com && echo mail sended) \
|| (cat JOB$SLURM_JOB_ID.out |mail -s "$SLURM_JOB_NAME Failed after $(secs_to_human $(($(date +%s) - ${start}))) id=$SLURM_JOB_ID" my@email.com && echo mail sended && exit $?)
```

you can also edit this to send seperate stdout/stderr logs or attach them as files.

This snippet is also shared on [github-gists](https://gist.github.com/ultranity/d672ba80b79a4d9b0e2c807c2a106260)

Answer (score 0):

You might also be interested in Slurm-Mail: https://github.com/neilmunday/slurm-mail

Slurm-Mail allows you to customise HTML emails sent to users and provides more information than the emails sent by Slurm by default.

Note: this tool requires admin (root) privileges to install and configure.

Comment: This is a good alternative, but better to specify that you have to be able to be the administrator to install it (which isn't the most common use-case scenario of job schedulers)

Comment: I disagree, most job schedulers, e.g. Slurm, PBS/Torque etc. require root privileges to install and configure them.

Comment: this tool is not very useful. You need superuser privileges.

Comment: you need admin access to the HPC cluster.

Comment: I have updated my post with a note to say that admin privileges are required to use the tool.

Answer (score -4):

`--mail-user=<user>`
User to receive email notification of state changes as defined by `--mail-type` . The default value is the submitting user.

And there is an odther parameter is : `--mail-type=<type>`  , it allows you to Notify user by email when certain event types occur. Valid type values are **NONE**, **BEGIN**, **END**, **FAIL**, **REQUEUE** , **INVALID_DEPEND** , **STAGE_OUT**