Sending a customized email related to a job submitted with `sbatch`
I am trying to send a customized email related to my job submitted through slurm on cluster following this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/73293621/7094175, but when I tested the mail server by executing echo 'abc' | mail -s "hello" user@host.edu, I got this error
postdrop: warning: unable to look up public/pickup: No such file or directory. It seems like the mail is not properly configured on my campus' cluster. Is there an alternative to the above method of sending a customized mail such as modifying the default mail that slurm sends? I want to avoid contacting the cluster admin to resolve the mail error, they are slow.
